# google test: code coverage for shared library

Tags: unit-testing, c++11, testing, code-coverage, googletest

I have written **main.cc** which call unit test code available in  shared library **libAmazonplugin.so** . Problem is code coverage is only captured for **main.cpp** but not for the actual definition inside **libAmazonplugin.so**

This is **main.cpp** files which call unit test available in libAmazonplugin.so

```
main.cpp **// code coverage is captured**

#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
             
  int ret = run_test(argc,argv); // call to libAmazonplugin.so
}
```

Here is definition of **run_test** inside **libAmazonplugin.so** .
Problem: why **amazonclient.h** code coverage is not captured

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include "amazonclient.h" // code coverage is not capture why??

AmazonClient*obj = nullptr;

class AmazonPlugin: public ::testing::Test {
public:

  void SetUp( ) {
  
      if(obj== nullptr){
               
        obj = new AmazonClient();
          }
      
   }

   void TearDown( ) {
      if(obj!=nullptr){
        
          }
        }
};

TEST_F(AmazonPlugin, isRunning)
{
        if(obj!=nullptr){
                 EXPECT_EQ(false, obj->isRunning());
        }
        else{
              //no obj
        }
}

 int run_test(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
        ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
         return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

compiled command

```
 g++ main.cpp -I/usr/lib/  -std=c++11 -g -O0 -pthread -lgtest -lpthread -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -lAmazonplugin
```

Comment: Can any one help please. I tired adding --coverage flag on the linking of the dynamic library as well but no luck . i.e   g++ --coverage main.cpp -I/usr/lib/  -std=c++11 -g -O0 -pthread -lgtest -lpthread -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage --coverage -lAmazonplugin

Comment: Adding coverage flags to the linking won't do anything. You need to, at the very least, compile the library code with coverage instrumentation enabled. It's not enough to link after the fact if coverage was never enabled in the first place. However I can't guarantee that would be sufficient. I'm currently trying to solve the same problem.